# Handle all links and forms with ajax - Zepto

Tags: ajax, forms, hyperlink, zepto

jquery mobile by default handles all clicks on links and form submits via ajax call. How can i achieve the same with Zepto libary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't tested it yet but it should work like this

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(){ 
        var link = $(this).attr("href") 
        $.get(link, function(response){
            $("#myContainer").append(response)
        })

        return false
    })
})
```

Comment: click() is not available with zepto :-(

Comment: seems like click() is deprecated since the release of zepto 1.0

you can achieve the exact same thing by using on("click")

`$("a").on("click", function(){ ... });`